# Android notification Icon remains the default icon, even after change

Tags: java, android, notifications

This problem simply puzzles me. I uploaded a new icon for my app, the app's Icon on my phone's dashboard changed. However, the notification Icon remains the same default green floating android, although I declared a different Icon while setting the notification - I also see the correct icon in Android Studio's preview near the line number, but still nothing.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"123")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground))
                .setContentTitle("Reminder: "+title)
                .setContentText("Go do it TIGER!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invalidate the cache with :

Android Studio menu -> Files -> invalidate caches / restart

And in your phone uninstall the app

Comment: Edit: I did what you said, it didn't work, however I tried choosing the Icon by creating a new image asset, and choosing notification icon.
I uploaded my custom app Icon, and it showed as blank white square. However, when I changed setSmallIcon to that blank Icon (which was supposed to be the app's custom Icon), it suddenly worked!

Answer (score 0):

Android caches notification channel settings so changing the channel ID int the builder also works. I don't know how to invalidate this cache.

`NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"456")`